# React Checkbox when checked apparently does not do anything

Tags: reactjs

The react checkbox does not do anything when it's clicked. The following code is supposed to delete each option when it's clicked but either nothing is being deleted, or if it is it isn't correctly updating the list on display.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

import Option from './option.js';

class TaskTracker extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            options: ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4",
                      "Option 5", "Option 6", "Option 7", "Option 8"]
        };
        this.moveFromOptions=this.moveFromOptions.bind(this);
    }

    moveFromOptions(option) {
        let index = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.options.length; i++) {
            if (this.state.options[i] === option) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        this.state.options.splice(index, 1);
    }

    render() {
        return (<div className="task-tracker">
            <div className="lists">
                <div className="options">
                    <div className="options-menu">
                        {this.state.options.map((option, index) =>
                            <Option option={option} key={index} action={this.moveFromOptions}/>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>);
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TaskTracker />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**options.js**

```
import React from 'react';
const Option = props => {
    const {option, name, action} = props;
    return (<div className="option">
        <input type="checkbox" key={name} checked={action}/>
        <label htmlFor={name}>{option}</label>
    </div>)
}

export default Option;
```

Comment: Try `onChange={action}` instead of `checked={action}`

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova no, that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: `onChange={()=>action(option)}`? Actually, that won't do it either as you mutate the state, so React won't pick up the change

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova I don't know how a stateless version of the above would look like.

Comment: It doesn't need to be stateless, you just need to clone options and call `setState` https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate (I'm sure someone will give you an answer in more detail, but if not I'll do tomorrow morning, bed time for me)

Comment: Here is a working version in case you still need it https://jsfiddle.net/v2osjgyL/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change two points to make it work:

- you need to use the `onChange` props on the input, `checked` is be a boolean stating if the checkbox is checked or not
- you need to use `this.setState` to trigger a re-render with your updated state

Here is a working demo : https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-fast-5xu9v?file=/src/App.js.